# PHP Session Variable - Property access is not allowed yet

Tags: session-variables

I have the following code at the top of my index.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'includes/db_connect.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['conn'])){
    $_SESSION['conn'] = db_connect('igslogistics01');
}

var_dump($_SESSION);


?>
```

The result of the output is:

**Warning: var_dump(): Property access is not allowed yet**

I have seen similar questions asked, related mainly to db connections but as you can see in my case I can't access any of the session variable.

The server is running PHP v 7.1.0

Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated.